# classcastexception on reading xml node

Tags: java, android, xml

i'll try to read an xml, following a tutorial finded online here http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

```
public String leggi_palinsesto()
{
    String comodo="";
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    // looping through all item nodes <item>

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        //Element e = null;
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        String titolo = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITOLO); // name child value
        String artista = parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTISTA); // cost child value
        System.out.println(artista+" - "+titolo);
        comodo=artista+" - "+titolo;
    }

    return comodo;
}
```

When the debug arrive to `Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);` return classcastexception error, but I'm sure that's the correct code.

This is the Logcat

```
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at it.axiomatic.radioamicizia.RadioAmiciziaActivity.leggi_palinsesto(RadioAmiciziaActivity.java:254)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at it.axiomatic.radioamicizia.RadioAmiciziaActivity$1$1.run(RadioAmiciziaActivity.java:121)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-06 18:03:14.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the .xml file:

```
http://www.radioamicizia.com/demo.xml
```

EDIT: I've tried with original example xml file (http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml), but at casting of node to element... ERROR!

EDIT:

```
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITOLO = "name";
static final String KEY_ARTISTA = "cost";
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: debug to the exact line. and attach the error log stacktrace

Comment: I dont know what do you want I trace, but the problem is when I try to casting the node like element, because the node contain information.  :(

Answer (score 2):

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#item%28int%29):

> public Node item(int index)

`NodeList.item(i)` returns a `Node` not an `Element`. The node can be anything else not just an `Element` and that explains why you are getting that error.

If you want to process only elements of your XML, you should do this check before:

```
if(nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
  Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
  // Process element here
}
```

**EDIT** Replace your `for` loop with this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    if(nl.item(i).getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            continue;

    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    String titolo = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITOLO); // name child value
    String artista = parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTISTA); // cost child value
    System.out.println(artista+" - "+titolo);
    comodo=artista+" - "+titolo;
}
```

Comment: Tried, but at first check enter in the condition and at the assign return me the error. Maybe something wrong in xml?

Comment: Did you replace the whole for loop? See my edit for an update

Comment: :( The cast of the node to element generate always same error... :( :(

Comment: Can you show us the value of the `KEY_ITEM`, `KEY_TITOLO` and `KEY_ARTISTA` values?

Comment: Sure, I'm edited. But i dont think this is the problem, because NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); dont creates problem, but only when i try to cast crash.